# Redirect Scala-Sbt application output to a file

Tags: scala, shell, sbt

I am trying to debug the logs of an application on the localhost.

```
sbt "run 9001" > logFile
```

And this doesn't work. In the log file along with other lines i see this:

```
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/----/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading settings for project -build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from ----
[info] loading settings for project --- from build.sbt ...
[info] loading settings for project slickCodeGenProject from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to serenity (in build file:)

[35m--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---[0m

[[37minfo[0m] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9001

[32m(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)[0m

[[37minfo[0m] p.c.s.NettyServer - Stopping server...
```

I saw many questions related to this on stack overflow but nothing seemed to have worked for me in this case. Please suggest if there are any possible ways that we can redirect the logs of the running application to the logfile.
Cheers.

Comment: Why not just configure your logging library to write to a file instead?

Comment: are you using a logging framework such as log4j, logback, or any other logger? In that case you can setup your logger and make the logs of the app (I guess it's built on top of Play Framework) go anywhere you want (standard output, file, etc).

Comment: The task is to measure the performance of the application. Application will need to run multiple times with multiple instances on  localhost. the log files that will get generated will need to be investigated further for analysis.

Comment: Also, Is it possible to run sbt "run 9001" command as background process.

Comment: If you want to measure performances, use proper tooling for that, not output logs. Moreover `sbt run` is an interactive mode which won't provide performance similar to the ones you'll have when really running the application outside SBT in production.